# Is it possible to use dotTrace profiler from command line?

Tags: dottrace

I have to automate our build/integration process and an important part of it are two reports generated by dotTrace profiler. At the moment these reports are done manually. The documentation is very scarce though it is mentioned the command line scenario is possible.

Is it possible to use dotTrace from command line?

Thanks in advance,
Don

Answer (score 0):

Such feature is scheduled for the next version.
It is not available now.

Comment: Thank you Ivan.
Which feature are you referring to? The integration with Performance Test projects or the command line?

Answer (score -1):

No, until now (dotTrace 5) there is no command line support. 
Follow this thread:
http://devnet.jetbrains.net/thread/304144

ANTS Performance Profiler does support command line. We have incorporated it into our continuous integration process and it works well.
http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/